# Error installing Yaws server on Windows 7

Tags: windows, yaws

When installing Yaws, I get below error reports:

> 1. Cannot Open "c:/program Files/Yaws-2.0.2/logs/localhost.auth"
> 2. Cannot Open "c:/program Files/Yaws-2.0.2/logs/localhost.access"

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: please any one to help can send me a response hear. thanxs with kind regards.

Comment: Does the folder `C:/Program Files/Yaws-2.0.2/logs` exist?

Comment: No please. It was empty